# Setting pannel tab disclosed in ADF not working

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, tabpanel

I have a project in ADF which contains a jsff page with a tabbed panel. I have a sample check for that which tab of the panel to be opened but the code not works (when I run the program I do not see any differences). The tab is changed only when I refresh the entire page. I am looking for a mistake in the code but I can`t find it. Could you help me with some ideas?

```
        RichPanelTabbed richPanelTabbed = getPanelTabBind();
        for (UIComponent child : richPanelTabbed.getChildren()) {
            RichShowDetailItem sdi = (RichShowDetailItem) child;

            if ("a".equals(sdi.getId())
                 sdi.setDisclosed(true);
            } else if ("b".equals(sdi.getId())){
                 sdi.setDisclosed(true);
            } else {
                 sdi.setDisclosed(false);
            }
        AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(panelTabBind);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the addPartialTarget to the layout container that include your panelTab